# How do I get Abyss Web Server to work with Template Toolkit?

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

The Abyss Web server only seems to like CGI, but I am switching everything I am doing to Template Toolkit. Whenever I try to process my forms, Abyss complains of bad CGI headers.

Comment: CGI is a way for a web server to communicate with a program instead of a file. Template-Toolkit is a way to generate that data. They are not interchangeable and are often used together.

Comment: I am using them together. I am getting form data with CGI, and printing the results to a different page with TT.

Comment: And you aren't outputting the right headers.

Comment: This is the part I can't figure out with Abyss as I am using the same header info I used when it was all straight CGI....

Comment: We can't figure it out either. You haven't given us any of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

You absolutely need the `Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1` line at the very top of the page.